# How do we pass data into this.state - React.js?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I've created a React component in my JSX file and in the constructor I have:

```
this.state = {data: [[200,100],[50,60],[100,300]] };
```

This is completely fine.  It runs nicely.

However, if I add:

```
this.state = {linedata: [{x:200,y:100},{x:50,y:60},{x:100,y:300}] };
```

I get:

```
d3.js:265 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I am very lost as to why this is the case.  Is the data supposed to be formatted in a certain way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, each component's `state` is a simple JavaScript object. In your first example, since you said the component renders well, it seems like your component utilizes the `data` property of `this.state`.

If you change it to `this.state.linedata`, `this.state.data` will be `undefined`. You should probably update your component to read from `this.state.linedata` instead of `this.state.data`.

More examples of how you wrote your `render` function and ways you used d3 in your code would be helpful in giving you a more precise and helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you attempting to reassign `this.state` after the initial assignment?  You should never manually set component state; instead use [`this.setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).